# Unable to retrievw data of firebase current online user

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve data of specific node (clicksRemain) of current online user from firebase into a textView but the data is not showing. Below is my code.

**PracticeActivity**

```java
public class PracticeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView link1;
    DatabaseReference dRef;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
   


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_practice);

        link1 = findViewById(R.id.link1);
        
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        dRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        if (user != null) {
            dRef.child("clicksRemain").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    String remainingClicks = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    link1.setText(remainingClicks);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
        }else{
            link1.setText("10");
        }
    }
    }
```

I think the code is correct to check if a user is logged in or not as if a user is logout then the app shows the value 10 as written in this code.

[Snapshot of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/932JW.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag. This also has the advantage that your code get syntax highlighting right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done these changes and now successfully retrieved the data.

```
 FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

 String uID = user.getUid();
 dRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

 dRef.child(uID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            String remainingClicks = String.valueOf(snapshot.child("clicksRemain").getValue(Integer.class));
            link1.setText(remainingClicks);
  }
```